# Model loaders work in Chrome but not in Meta Quest 2 Browser, when using file input tag

Tags: three.js, blob, html-input, oculusquest

If I upload a .glb model with `<input type="file">` tag and GLTF loader, it works as expected on Chrome on Windows and Android, but does not work on Meta Quest 2 Browser.

This is the code part that handles model loading:

```
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file') as HTMLInputElement
fileInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => loadModel((e.target as HTMLInputElement).files![0]))
function loadModel(file: File) {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)

    const loader = new GLTFLoader()
    
    loader.load( url, function ( gltf ) {
        scene.add( gltf.scene );
        console.log('Model loaded')

    }, undefined, function ( error ) {

        console.error( error );

    } );
}
```

When I choose the .glb file on Meta Quest 2 Browser, on the console I get:

```
GET blob:https://192.168.1.161:5500/83bfd355-2cf6-4714-bda7-3c6cf3331c58 
net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 200 (OK)
load    @   three.module.js:41933
load    @   GLTFLoader.js:222
loadModel   @   index.ts:58
(anonymous) @   index.ts:52

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: network error
Promise.then (async)        
readData    @   three.module.js:41973
start   @   three.module.js:41969
(anonymous) @   three.module.js:41966
Promise.then (async)        
load    @   three.module.js:41934
load    @   GLTFLoader.js:222
loadModel   @   index.ts:58
(anonymous) @   index.ts:52
```

Request details:

```
User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; Quest 2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) OculusBrowser/29.0.0.3.52.509692587 SamsungBrowser/4.0 Chrome/116.0.5845.114 VR Safari/537.36

Request URL:
blob:https://192.168.1.161:5500/83bfd355-2cf6-4714-bda7-3c6cf3331c58
Request Method:
GET
Status Code:
200 OK
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I recreated the problem in a sample web app here:

https://fornaeffe.github.io/vr-playground/

source code here:

https://github.com/fornaeffe/vr-playground/tree/visorr-upload-bug

- GLTF loader works as expected also on Meta Quest 2 Browser if it loads a model from the server, it fails only when loading a model though input tag.
- OBJ loader behaves in the same way (ok on Chrome, fails in Meta Quest 2
- Texture loader do well both on Windows and Meta Quest 2 Browser even from file input tag.

I resumed the test I did in this table:

|  | Chrome on Windows | Chrome on Android | Browser on Meta Quest 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Texture loader from server | OK | OK | OK |
| Texture loader from file input tag | OK | OK | OK |
| GLTF loader from server | OK | not tried | OK |
| GLTF loader from file input tag | OK | OK | FAILS! |
| OBJ loader from file input tag | OK | not tried | FAILS! |

I’m using three.js version 0.156

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Thank you!

**Update:**

This seems a Meta Quest 2 Browser bug: I tried **changing manually the extension** of the model file from .glb to .png, and the model loads correctly!